# Img:hover not working

Tags: css, image, hover

My Problem is I want to have an image, which i positioned precisely, which grows when i hover on it. I did it with .name:hover{..} but nohing happens ? What is the problem ? 
Here my Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<body background="img/BG.jpg" </body>
    <title>NBA</title>
    <a href="SeiteInfos.html"> <h1 class="p">NBA-Infos</h1> </a>
    <style type="text/css">


h1{text-align:center;
    color:orange;
    Border: 3px solid green;
    margin:10px 600px;
    Border-radius:10px;}

#text1{text-align:center;
       color:#E0F2F7;
       font-family:Algerian;
       font-size:20px;}



 #seite2{color:#0066CC; font-size :15px; text-align: bottom-right;}



    .p:hover {
    position: relative; 
    top: -3px; 
    left: -3px; 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #E76F1A, 
            2px 2px #E76F1A, 
            3px 3px #E76F1A, 
            4px 4px #E76F1A, 
            5px 5px #E76F1A, 
            6px 6px #E76F1A}

    #ho{width:20px; height: 60px;
    color: red;}


    img[class*="pic_"]{position:absolute;
                    z-index:-2;
                     -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
                     -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
                     -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
                     transition: all 1s ease-in-out;}



    .pic_chicago{left:735px;
                 top:247px;}

    .pic_Atlanta{top:474px;
                 left:950px; }

    .pic_Atlanta:hover{transform: scale(1.7);
                       -ms-transform: scale(1.7); /* IE 9 */
                       -webkit-transform: scale(1.7); /* Safari and Chrome */}


    </style>
</head>





    <p id="text1">Auf die Überschrift klicken um auf die Infoseite zu gelangen. Auf die verschiedenen Staaten klicken, um auf die offizielle Teamseite zu gelangen.</p>
    <p id="seite2"><a href="MyHomepage2.html">Hier kommt ihr zur nächsten Seite!</p></a>
    <div id="ho">    </div>
    <div id="pics">
<img src="img/chicago.png" class="pic_chicago"/>
<img src="img/Atlanta-Hawks.png" class="pic_Atlanta" />
```

Thanks for Your help :D

Comment: what element do you want to react when hovering? you have '.p:hover', which will apply to all elements with class 'p'. you may need 'p:hover'

Comment: P is working fine, the problem are the images "pic_chicago,pic_Atlanta"

Comment: Why do you have z-index:-2 on img? Could that be causing the hover issue? You transition code seems to work fine. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RnqU9/).

Comment: Because i want it to be underneath other Elements

Comment: IT WAS THE PROBLEM THANKS A LOT :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes are meant to used repeatedly, and ids are meant to be unique. So instead of having unique classes, you might want to consider switching them to ids and adding all the common images a class (for example: `team`).

Them define a hover state for that class in order to cover the hover state for all the team images. In your case, you can also use `#pics img` selector.

```
#pics img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.7);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.7);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.7);
```

}

See a simple example I made here: http://jsfiddle.net/DsQq6/

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but first all the classes were divs, it didn't work so i tried classes, and the shared class idea isn't working either: I transformed the classes into divs and added an aditional class aside.

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/DsQq6/1/ You know you can have as many classes as you want? So, you can define a `hoverImage` class, for example. `.hoverImage:hover {scale(1.7)}`... then, on whatever element you put, that element will scale on hover... Plenty of possibilities you have! :)

Comment: THE PROBLEM IS SOLVED: IT WAS THE Z_INDEX :D 
THANKS

Comment: So the mouse was never over an image, but over other elements? :)  In future, you can check this by right-clicking the image and selecting Inspect Element - it will show you on what element is the mouse on.